# How to draw iphone message like added image. 

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics

[alt text http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/tn1270646423002339600.png](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/tn1270646423002339600.png)

I want to draw like that.

How do I draw like that? Do I use Quartz-core? 
please advice for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the image, then set it as the background will solve your issue. Don't need to use Quartzcore, you can create a text field, or a label or a button with the background as your image. And you are all set!